# Is there a way to list number of files when using dpkg -L to list files of a package?

Tags: debian, shell, zsh, dpkg

I use `cat -n` to get a line listing of the content in a `.txt` file.

```
[$] cat exam.txt                                                                                                                    
     1  let's see how far does this go, and if it works or not. if not till where it 
     2  goes and what happens after that. In nano, things are much more better than in X 
     3  text editors as there is no set fill therein as there is in nano and hence are 
     4  much worse off.
```

In dpkg there doesn't seem to do that, or is there ? I am on Debian testing and running dpkg 1.18.18 . Just to make the listing less cumbersome, am using head -

```
[$] dpkg -L nano | head

/.
/bin
/bin/nano
/etc
/etc/nanorc
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/nano
/usr/share/doc/nano/AUTHORS
```

Because I'm using head I know these are 10 lines or 10 files, considering . as a file as well. I did try something like -

```
$ dpkg -nL nano
```

But got the error it doesn't know that option.

If it's not possible, please let me know so I can file it as a feature-request in `dpkg`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dpkg -L nano | cat -n
```

does the trick... (It counts directories as well as files though.)

If you just want the total,

```
dpkg -L nano | wc -l
```

Comment: Another application that does line numbering and is in coreutils is `nl`.

Comment: you meant `nl` it was reading as 1.