# How to tack to dpkg -L output with line numbers?

Tags: shell, dpkg

I asked [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339844/is-there-a-way-to-list-number-of-files-when-using-dpkg-l-to-list-files-of-a-pac/) question. While I got the answer (and am beating myself why didn't I try to pipe the output via `cat` or `cat -n` as shared by Stephen). Is there a way to make an alias or something so that whenever I run

```
$ dpkg -L $PACKAGENAME
```

I get the listing with line numbers, is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alias part:

```
alias dpkgnum='function __dpkgnum { dpkg -L $1 | nl;};__dpkgnum'
```

As noted on comments, including just the function in  `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file, without alias will also work.

```
function dpkgnum { dpkg -L $1 | nl;}
#call it by terminal $: dpkgnum pkgname
```

In this case the function will not be visible as an alias but as a system function and can be listed (among other system vars) with `declare`.

Comment: Why not simply `function dpkgnum {dpkg -L "$1 | nl;}`?

Comment: why an alias to call a function? Why not just directly calling the function?

Comment: @muru By declaring the function directly without an alias i suppose that function and function name are "reserved" as a system var. Could this be a conflict if it happened another function with same name (dpkgnum) to be declared/used in a shell script ...?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou not unless you export the function

Answer (score 4):

```
dpkg -L $PACKAGENAME | nl
```

`nl` is a utility to tack line numbers on any standard output or provided input file.

Comment: yours is good but as I shared, I didn't want to remember to use `nl` all the time. Regretably, would have to go with George on this one.